# How get all messages from folder in ImapX 2?

Tags: c#, imap

i am using ImapX 2 and i wanted to get messages and attachments from all folders

That is my code, i can get all folders, but messages not. How to get messages?

```
if (client.Login(login, pass))
                {
                    // login successful
                    FolderCollection folders = client.Folders;
                    foreach (Folder myfolder in folders)
                    {

                        var messages = myfolder.Messages;

                        foreach (var message in messages)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(message.Subject);
                            var attachments = message.Attachments;
                            if (attachments.Count() > 0)
                                foreach (var attachment in attachments)
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show(attachment.FileName);
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you can access message you need to download them

`myfolder.Messages.Download();
foreach (var message in messages)
{//your code}`

You can use parameter’s, here what documentation said

`public void Download([string query = "ALL"], [ImapX.Enums.MessageFetchMode mode = ImapX.Enums.MessageFetchMode.ClientDefault], [int count = -1])
    Member of ImapX.Collections.MessageCollection`

Summary:
Downloads messages from server using default or given mode.

Parameters:
query: The search query to filter messages. ALL by default
mode: The message fetch mode, allows to select which parts of the message will be requested.
count: The maximum number of messages that will be requested. Set count to -1 will request all messages which match the given query.